# How do you bind a function that is receiving parameters to a button with jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we get an incoming call, it fires the function below.  You can see in the code that we then show a confirm popup that allows us to answer or decline the call.

However, I would like it to actually fire a different function that will then allow us to play a sound and make a button blink until the user can click the button thereby giving us more flexibility that just the standard confirm popup.  I can obviously get it to fire a function, but how to I pass the right properties to that function so that I can accept or decline the call by clicking on the button?

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function(conn) {
            startRing();
            $('.answer').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.answer').removeClass('hide');
            $('.ignore').removeClass('hide');
            if (confirm('Accept incoming call from ' + conn.parameters.From + '?')) {
             connection = conn;
             conn.accept();
             console.log(conn.parameters);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Does it have to be a modal dialogue?

Comment: No, I would prefer to just have a few buttons on the page rather than a modal style popup.

Comment: OK. So what stops you? Dynamically create a blinking button with callback defined in the main function. Callback will stop the blinking and perform whatever it needs and removes the button.  Simple closure solution. Or create the whole form dynamically.  Or instead of creating/deleting do show/hide.

Comment: I can see how to activate the button, but how do I make it so when the user clicks it, it activates the conn.accept() portion?

Comment: Define a callback function for the button inside yours. As a nested function it will have access to the enclosing scope, and therefore to `conn`.